# error running a dockerfile that use go and makke file : error 1

Tags: docker, go, makefile, paypal

hi am trying to clone this repository and run the docker file to create a load-watcher images but i am getting this error and it's not working i try to search by my self but i am stuck because am a beginner in go and make files

so this is the repository:
https://github.com/paypal/load-watcher.git
this is the first command am trying to run (it's right in the top of the read-me file of the repository):
`sudo docker build -t load-watcher .`

and this is the error:

```
Step 1/7 : FROM golang:1.16
 ---> 972d8c0bc0fc
Step 2/7 : WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/paypal/load-watcher
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 34ef186a096c
Step 3/7 : COPY . .
 ---> 5361f9fef122
Step 4/7 : RUN make build
 ---> Running in 51d0b4396ecc
GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 CGO_ENABLED=0 /usr/local/go/bin/go  build -o bin/load-watcher main.go
go: github.com/francoispqt/gojay@v1.2.13: Get "https://proxy.golang.org/github.com/francoispqt/gojay/@v/v1.2.13.mod": dial tcp: lookup proxy.golang.org on 194.167.49.3:53: read udp 172.17.0.2:58077->194.167.49.3:53: i/o timeout
make: *** [Makefile:24: build] Error 1
The command '/bin/sh -c make build' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

please if any one work with this or know how to help i will be grateful, i have been trying to solve it for a week now !!!!

Comment: The error shows problems contacting the go proxy. Does your build system have a network path to the internet? Does this work `curl 'https://proxy.golang.org/github.com/francoispqt/gojay/@v/v1.2.13.mod'` ?

Comment: thank you for responding , yes it work and give me the modules github.com/francoispqt/gojay
 but the there is a go 1.12 written and i installed the 1.19

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i am trying to solve that problem. i clone that reposotory and run the make file and try to build the image from the Dockerfile but i alwas getting that error. so i need to solve it. i make sure that the curl command that you ask for is working. if you need any other additional ditails please tell.

Comment: hi guys, i just want  to say that i am still stuck here and i really need help if there is any one